# How do you add information to a polygon from multiple polygons based on location in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, attribute-table, select-by-location, multiple

I have a couple of points and have made a buffer layer of 1km around each point, which contain information about which point it represents. I have another raster layer (containing information regarding land use) that I converted into polygons and selected the ones that were within the 1km buffer. What I want to do now is to add which buffers cover which polygons. The problem occurs when one polygon is within multiple buffers, like the example I have marked in the picture (polygon with red edges). I have tried using the tools Union and NNJoin, but I only get one buffer per polygon. Does anyone know how to solve this?
[image]

Comment: Look at the Overlap Analysis tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the field calculator for this together with the overlay functions. The expression would be something like this one:

```
array_to_string( overlay_intersects('buffer_layer', "fieldname_to_collect"),', ')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the tool [Intersection](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_overlay_tools.html#id33). This should select all the buffers which intersect with the landuse-polygons.